# Loop through Array of items with key value pair

Tags: database, firebase, loops, nsarray, for-in-loop

I have this function named “addToBasketButtonPressed()” to add item Id in my basket with default quantity 1 and the function name “incrementQty” called after else is checking if item to append already exist in basket and if it does then just increase the qty by 1.

```
    @objc func addToBasketButtonPressed() {
    //check if user is logged in or show login view
    if MUser.currentUser() != nil {

        downloadBasketFromFirestore(MUser.currentId()) { (basket) in
            if basket == nil {
                self.createNewBasket()
            }else {

                self.incrementQty(basketId: basket!.id, itemToUpdate: self.item!.id, deltaQty: 1)

                let qty: Int = 1
                let item = self.item.id
               // let dataTosave = ("Item", item!, "Qty", qty)
                let dataTosave: [String: Any] = ["\(item)": qty]

                basket?.itemIds.append("\(dataTosave)")

                print("basket id is \(basket!.id)")
                print("current item name is \(self.item.name)")

                self.updateBasket(basket: basket!, withValues: [kITEMIDS: basket!.itemIds!])
```

Here’s the function to increment qty by 1 which is erroring.

**Error 1**=
**Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[String : Any]'** on line = **for item in itemArray {**

**Error 2**=
**Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'** on last 3 lines

```
    func incrementQty (basketId: String, itemToUpdate: String, deltaQty: Int) {

    FirebaseReference(.Basket).document(basketId).getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
                   print(error.localizedDescription)
                   return
        }

        if let documentData = documentSnapshot?.data() {

            print("item exists. update qty")
            print("document data in itemIds", documentData)

            let itemArray = documentData["itemIds"] as? [String: Int]
            print("items in item array \(itemArray)")

                    for item in itemArray! {

                    if item["Id"] == itemToUpdate {
                    print("checking document with id", item["Id"])
                    (item["Qty"] as! Int) + deltaQty
                }
            }
```

If I comment out the last 4 lines of code and amend below codes by commenting out **“as? [String: Any]’** as shown below then in the debug window I can see the list of items. If I don’t comment out **“as? [String: Any]”** then it’s nil.

```
                let itemArray = documentData["itemIds"] // as? [String: Int]
            print("items in item array \(itemArray)")
```

[image]

My question is how do I loop through this list to check if item user is appending to basket already exists and if it does then just increase the quantity by 1 else add with default quantity 1?

note: data is extracted from Firebase Database.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I've replaced pictures with actual text. Not had any response to my post yet, is this something you can help me with?